# How to use prepared statments for INSERTs with asyncpg?

Tags: prepared-statement, asyncpg

The package docs https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#prepared-statements.

The only coroutines seem to be dealing with SELECT queries with prepared statements. The docs list `cursor`, `explain`, `fetch`, `fetchrow`, `fetchval`.  It doesn't appear obvious whether `asyncpg` supports prepared INSERT statements. I tried `stmt.execute(...)` as a guess and indeed the `PreparedStatement` object has no attribute `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's you on github, but here's the answer for the others who might be looking into this: you can use any of `fetch*` methods. [Reference](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/392).